# How to use getattr or getattribute to correctly raise ImportError while calling some methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pep

Hello their thanks in advance for helping me,

Please see below code:

```py
import types

_MSG = ("Failed importing {name}. Please install {name}."
        " Using pip install {name}")

class Empty(): # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """Empty class for beam API."""
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return None

class DummyBeam(types.ModuleType): # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods

    DoFn = Empty
    Pipeline = Empty

    def __init__(self, name="apache_beam"):
        super(DummyBeam, self).__init__(name)

    def __getattribute__(self, _):
        if getattr(DummyBeam, _, None) is Empty:

            err_msg = _MSG.format(name=self.__name__)
            raise ImportError(err_msg)
```

What I want to check if `apache_beam` was not installed it will successfully load all beam classes like DoFn and pipeline but calling some function raises error please see below code to see above code in use.

```py
try:
  import apache_beam as beam
except ImportError:
  beam = DummyBeam()

class SomeFn(beam.DoFn):
  pass

class SomeOtherFn(beam.Pipeline):
  pass

SomeFn()
```

In above code for now accessing `beam.DoFn` raises error but what I want it to not raise error when accessing `beam.DoFn` although it raises error when calling `SomeFn()`. Also tried to replace `getattribute` with `getattr` and it not gives me results as i expected it wont raise error when calling SomeFn() although it runs fine for all codes.

Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the traceback (that you should have posted FWIW), your error is not in *calling* `SomeFn()` but in *accessing* `beam.DoFn` in the `SomeFn` class definition. And the reason is quite obvious: you very explicitely instructed Python to do so by plain overriding `Beam.__getattribute__`.

Note that `object.__getattribute__` is the official default implementation of attribute lookup (it's invoked each time Python sees either `obj.name` or getattr(obj, "name"), and that it's a method that is better left alone unless you fully understand the implications of overriding it AND have no better solution.

In this case the very obvious solution is to instead implempent `__getattr__`, which is only invoked by `__getattribute__` as a last resort if the attribute couldn't be resolved in any other way. You say that:

> Also replace getattribute with getattr was not working

but I just tried it on your code snippet and it (of course) yield the result I expected. Whether this is what *you* expected is another question, but since you neither posted this version of your code nor cared to explain how it "was not working", you can't expect any answer on this point (hint: "is not working" is a **totally useless** description of an issue).

As a last note:

> it will successfully load all beam methods like DoFn and pipeline
>   ...
>   In above code for now calling beam.DoFn

It seems you're a bit confused about terminology. `DoFn` and `Pipeline` are classes, not methods, and (as already mentionned) your error is raised when *accessing* `beam.DoFn`, not when *calling* it.

**EDIT:**

> by was not working I meant it not gives me error either when i am trying to access beam.DoFn or SomeFn() when use getattr instead getattribute
>   (...)
>   what i want is to raise error when calling someFn no accessing beam.DoFn

Ok, it looks that you don't quite get the execution order of a method call expression. When you do

```
obj.method()
```

this is actually a shortcut for

```
method = obj.__getattribute__("method")
method.__call__()
```

So overriding `__getattribute__` isn't the proper solution (cf above), and defining `__getattr__` is useless here - your `DummyBeam` class HAS `DoFn` and `Pipeline` attributes so `__getattr__` will just not be invoked for those names.

Now the reason you don't get any exception when calling `beam.DoFn` or `beam.Pipeline` is that those name are bound to your `Empty` **class**, not instances of that class, so you actually never invoke `Empty.__call__`. Rhe `__call__` method defined in a class is only used when an *instance* of that class is called, not when you instanciate the class (in which case it's the metaclass's `__call__` method which is invoked):

```
>>> class MyCallable:    
...     def __init__(self):
...         print("in MyCallable.__init__")
...     def __call__(self):
...         print("in MyCallable.__call__")
... 
>>>  
... c = MyCallable()
in MyCallable.__init__
>>> c()
in MyCallable.__call__
>>>
```

So if what you want is to raise your exception when someone tries to *instanciate* `DoFn` or ̀Pipeline`you either have to make them instances of`Empty`or keep them as they are and rename`Empty.**call**`to`Empty.**new**`which is the first method called by`type.**call**`(`type` being the default metaclass for all classes).

Comment: Thanks for explaining by was not working I meant it not gives me error either when i am trying to access beam.DoFn or SomeFn() when use getattr instead getattribute, also sorry for any trouble I should use proper words and what i want is to raise error when calling someFn no accessing beam.DoFn, it will help if you provide some solution. Above code raise error when access beam.DoFn but want to raise error when calling someFn()

Comment: very well explained thank you so much, I got by defining __new__ instead __call__ inside Empty class and raise exception there works fine, so there is no need for types.ModuleType? I want to use `self.__name__` while raising error so it use "apache_beam" as it uses SomeFn as name in error for now